# How to create a docker that runs a wget on cron and access the downloaded files via ftp on OpenShift?

Tags: docker, openshift

I would like to create a docker that runs a wget every minute in a cron indefinitely. To recover the files downloaded with wget, I would like to access via FTP. The FTP server used is vsftpd.

Locally docker works well and can access it via FTP, but when the docker is deployed on OpenShift, the container doesn't start and both, crond and vsftpd, doesn't run.

What changes must to do on this docker to run on OpenShift?

***Dockerfile:***

```
FROM alpine:3.4

RUN apk update && apk add vsftpd

RUN adduser -h /home/./files -s /bin/false -D files

RUN echo "local_enable=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo "chroot_local_user=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo "write_enable=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo "local_umask=022" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo "passwd_chroot_enable=yes" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo 'seccomp_sandbox=NO' >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo 'pasv_enable=Yes' >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo 'pasv_max_port=10100' >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo 'pasv_min_port=10090' >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && sed -i "s/anonymous_enable=YES/anonymous_enable=NO/" /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

RUN apk update && \ 
    apk add wget && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY myScript /bin/myScript
COPY cron /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
RUN chmod +x /bin/myScript

RUN echo "files:mypassword" |/usr/sbin/chpasswd
RUN chown files:files /home/files/ -R

EXPOSE 20 21 10090-10100

VOLUME /home/files

CMD /usr/sbin/crond -l 2 -L /var/log/cron.log | /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

***cron:***

```
* * * * * /bin/myScript
```

***myScript:***

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -P /home/files -nv http://www.google.com >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this on OpenShift Online or OpenShift Origin?

Comment: Your image looks like it will require ``root`` to work. OpenShift clusters would normally have ability to run images as ``root`` disabled. The ability to run images as ``root`` can only be granted by a cluster administrator. To debug locally what is happening, use ``docker run -u 100000`` to force container to run as non ``root`` user. Then you may see how it breaks.

Comment: OpenShift Online

Comment: I think that it's the problem, but, how can I create a user and put a password to be used by vsftpd if I not root?

Comment: When I execute docker `run -u 100000 <image name>` on local, docker doesn't start nor show anything. How can I view what is happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that cron always need root, so it can't start on OpenShift. To solve this problem, I've changed cron by [Supercronic](https://github.com/aptible/supercronic).

To download the data, I'm using the openshift client tools, using the `oc rsync` command